# Hibernate JPA one to one mapping with share primary key is causing the Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am new to Hibernate JPA. I am using eclipse kepler 4.3.2 and create a simple java project. I have a simple one to one mapping between the entiity MediaRequestDetails and MediaDetails.java objects with the shared primary key.

The primary key for the class `MediaRequestDetails(COLUMN="ID")` is been generated through sequence and the value of this field requestId is been shared with the class `MediaDetails.java(COLUMN="REQUEST_ID")`.I have the source entity like this MediaRequestDetails have skipped the getter and setters and package imports from source.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AW_REQUEST_DETAILS1")
public class MediaRequestDetails implements WFPayload , Serializable{
        /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name="REQUEST_ID_SEQ", sequenceName="REQUEST_ID_DBSEQ", allocationSize=1, initialValue = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "REQUEST_ID_SEQ")
        @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
        Long requestId;//id of the request


        @Column(name="REQUEST_TYPE", nullable = false)
        String requestType;//Type of the request Media/Non Media

        @Column(name="REQUESTOR", nullable = false)
        String requestor;//SOE ID of the requestor

        @Column(name="REQUESTOR_REGION")
        String requestorRegion;//This will be auto populated once the requestor is been added.

        @Column(name="REQUESTOR_TYPE") 
        String requestorType;//requestortype OBO,analyst or Coprorate Affairs

        @Column(name="EVENT_DATETIME")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        Date eventDate;//Date of the event // Please capture sate timezone as well

        @Column(name="EVENT_TYPE_ID")
        long eventType;//Type of the event

        @Column(name="PRINTED_MTRL")
        @Type(type="yes_no")
        boolean printedMTRL;//printed material will be produced or not

        @Column(name="IS_LOCATION_USA")
        @Type(type="yes_no")
        boolean locationIsUsa;//flag will this take place in USA or Not

        @Column(name="IS_ANALYST_ATTESTATION")
        @Type(type="yes_no")
        boolean hasAnalystAtts;

        @Column(name="ANALYST_ATTESTATION")
        String analystAtts;//AnalystAttastation

        @Column(name="ANALYST_DISCLOSURE")
        String analystDisclosure;//AnalystDisclosure

        @Column(name="ANALYST_DERV_POS")
        @Type(type="yes_no")
        boolean analystDervPos;//Information Regarding the Derivative Position(Y/N)

        @Column(name="ANALYST_POS_DETAILS")
        String analystPosdetails;//Information regarding Disclosure

        @Column(name="LAST_MODIFIED_BY") 
        String lastModifiedBy;//media request modified by name

        @Column(name="LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        Date lastModifiedDate;//date of the media request modified

        @Column(name="REQ_CREATED_BY")
        String createdBy;//media requestor creator user SOE Id.

        @Column(name="REQ_CREATE_DATE")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        Date createDate;//media requestor creator user SOE Id.

        @Column(name="REQUEST_STATUS")
        String requestStatus;//Setting the status of the Request

        @Column(name="PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID")
        Long procInstId;


        @Column(name="RSCH_APPRVL_FILE")
        @Lob
        byte[] rschApprvlFile;//Attached the approval of Research Management group

        @Column(name="CORP_APPRVL_FILE")
        @Lob
        byte[] coprApprvlFile;//Attached approval of coprorate group.

        @Column(name="IS_APPRVL_BY_CORP")
        @Type(type="yes_no")
        boolean hasApprovedByCorporate;//is request been approved by corporate

        @Column(name="IS_APPRVL_BY_RSCH")
        @Type(type="yes_no")
        boolean hasApprovedByRschMgmt;//is request been approved by rsch management

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="REQUEST_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
        Set<RequestDetailsCompanies> reqCompNotFoundDetails;

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="REQUEST_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
        Set<RequestDetailsCompanies> reqCompDiscussDetails;//Companies that are to be discussed

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="REQUEST_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
        Set<RequestDetailsCompanies> reqCompMayDiscussDetails;//Companies that may be discussed

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="REQUEST_ID",referencedColumnName="ID")
        Set<RequestDetailsCountries> reqContDiscussDetails;//Countries that are to be discussed

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="REQUEST_ID",referencedColumnName="ID")
        Set<RequestDetailsCountries> reqContMayDiscussDetails;///Countries that are to be discussed

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(columnDefinition="ID",referencedColumnName="REQUEST_ID")
        MediaDetails mediaDetails;//store the details of media in case of MeediaAppearance

        //getter setter methods for the fields
}
```

Source code for the MediaDetails.java. I have skipped the package imports and getter and setter methods from the class source code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AW_MEDIA_DETAILS")
public class MediaDetails implements WFPayload , Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "REQUEST_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    Long requestId;

    @Column(name="MEDIA_NAME")
    String mediaName;

    @Column(name="INTERVIEWER")
    String interviewer;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    String email;

    @Column(name="PHONE_NO")
    String phoneNo;

    @Column(name="INTRW_DETAILS")
    String intrwDetails;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="mediaDetails", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private MediaRequestDetails mediaRequDetails;

    //getter and setter methods are here
}
```

I am using the below source code to save the data but it is causing the issue while saving the data to the table associated withe MediaDetails.java class

```
public class TestRawsConnection {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("rawsjpa").createEntityManager();

        if(entityManager!=null){
            System.out.println("************* EntityManager is obtained 1234*****************");

            Date dt=new Date();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            MediaRequestDetails obj=new MediaRequestDetails();
            obj.setRequestor("jinesh");
            obj.setRequestorRegion("USA");
            obj.setRequestorType("OBO");
            obj.setRequestType("MediaAppr");
            obj.setEventDate(dt);
            obj.setEventType(12);
            obj.setLocationIsUsa(true);
            obj.setPrintedMTRL(false);
            obj.setLocationIsUsa(false);
            obj.setHasAnalystAtts(true);
            obj.setAnalystAtts("analystattestation");
            obj.setAnalystDisclosure("analystdisclosure");
            obj.setAnalystDervPos(true);
            obj.setAnalystPosdetails("analystposdetails");
            obj.setLastModifiedBy("jinesh");
            obj.setLastModifiedDate(dt);
            obj.setCreatedBy("jinesh123");
            obj.setCreateDate(dt);
            obj.setRequestStatus("pending");
            obj.setProcInstId(1234L);
            obj.setHasApprovedByCorporate(true);
            obj.setHasApprovedByRschMgmt(true);
            obj.setCoprApprvlFile(new String("Jinesh parikh").getBytes());
            obj.setRschApprvlFile(new String("Sejal Mehta").getBytes());

            MediaDetails md=new MediaDetails();
            md.setMediaName("test");

            obj.setMediaDetails(md);
            md.setMediaRequDetails(obj);
            entityManager.persist(obj);


            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

Below is the exception I am getting while saving the object in the database.

```
************* EntityManager is obtained 1234*****************
Hibernate: select REQUEST_ID_DBSEQ.nextval from dual
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.cira.raws.mediawf.bean.impl.MediaDetails
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:881)
    at TestRawsConnection.main(TestRawsConnection.java:60)
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.cira.raws.mediawf.bean.impl.MediaDetails
    at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:762)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:755)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.engine.spi.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:772)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:746)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:750)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:875)
    ... 1 more
```

Can anybody please tell me how to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `id` of object `MediaDetails` manually or add `@GeneratedValue` annotation to it. If it should be set by the database.

Here is an example for an auto-increment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AW_MEDIA_DETAILS")
public class MediaDetails implements WFPayload , Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "REQUEST_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    Long requestId;
    ....
```

Comment: So you are saying first I persist the object MediaRequestDetails and then I should fetch the generated Id using the getter method and then set the same Id to the MediaDetails object primary key field setter method and then persist the object MediaDetails?

Comment: @Beast no this will be done by jpa. The only think you have to set is the technical id of `MediaDetails`

Comment: I know you will find this stupid but I am new to Hibernate JPA so I am getting confused. can you please change in my source code and show it to me? Please it is a request.

Comment: @Beast No question is stupid. Only who ask can learn. I can not chnage your code because i not know how your algorithm for finding the id schold work. But i can give you an example, if the id should be an auto_inclement.

Comment: But Id over here is been set to the same value that is genearted by sequence mentioned in the MediaRequestDetails.java class. It is the case of the shared primary so in that case what annotation I should  write in the MediaDetails.java class requestId column? There is no algoritham used in my sample programe.

Comment: @Beast then read here http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.de/2014/05/onetoone-with-shared-primary-key.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a one-to-one relationship where you want to use the same primary key identifier in both entity classes: MediaRequestDetails and MediaDetails. In this case the primary key of the MediaDetails will also be the *foreign key* to MediaRequestDetails.

What you need to do is to put the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation in the MediaDetails class, specifically on the MediaRequestDetails field of MediaDetails entity class. In other words you must reverse the ownership of the relationship.
I've also added the @GenericGenerator annotation specifying the foreign strategy for the MediaDetails identifier.

In MediaRequestDetails the primary join column constraint is removed and the @OneToOne annotation must specify the mappedBy element.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AW_REQUEST_DETAILS1")
public class MediaRequestDetails ... {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="REQUEST_ID_SEQ", sequenceName="REQUEST_ID_DBSEQ", allocationSize=1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "REQUEST_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    Long requestId;//id of the request

    . . .

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="mediaRequDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    MediaDetails mediaDetails;//store the details of media in case of MeediaAppearance  

     // getter and setter methods
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "AW_MEDIA_DETAILS")
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="mediaRequDetails-primarykey", strategy="foreign",
    parameters={@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name="property", value="mediaRequDetails")
})
public class MediaDetails ... {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="mediaRequDetails-primarykey")
    @Column(name = "REQUEST_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    Long requestId;

    . . .

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private MediaRequestDetails mediaRequDetails;

    // getter and setter methods
}
```